# Pandas Table Data - Display LaTex Representation

Tags: python, pandas, latex, jupyter

I have a pandas dataframe where one column contains text and this text is a LaTex syntax descriptionof a mathematical symbol. When I display the table I'd like to see the mathematical symbol rendered (with the usual super and subscripts appearing) rather the than the bare LaTex syntax (with underscores and curly brackets etc.). I'd appreciate any help. I'm working in Jupyter Notebook the table data is as follows.

Thanks, C.

[image: hin]